# How to set DSCP in IP header for UDP socket in Windows

Tags: udp, ip, winsock, winsock2, qos

On my receiving device, it needs to have the DCSP field set to 0xff in order to properly receive and deal with incoming UDP packets.  On Linux, I can set `IPPROTO_IP`, `IP_TOS`, and everything works as expected (it being set in the header).  But not so with Windows.

I tried configuring `SIO_SET_QOS` with the line `int r = WSAIoctl( nSocket, SIO_SET_QOS, &QoS, sizeof( QoS ), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );` where `QoS` is a object of type `QOS` and is initialized. But it would only return -1, indicating it was not setting the service.  Also, even if this did work, I don't know how I would set the DCSP to 0xff, instead of letting Windows decide its service descriptor.

I saw references to `IP_DSCP_TRAFFIC_TYPE` but I can't seem to figure out what it is, or its #define type, and it appears to be EOL'd.

What can I do to set the Differentiated Services Code Point field in the IP header?